# image is not displayed from inside of different entry point

Tags: php, html, get

I have very simple mvc with small dispetcher, I get the url and split it. Then I search for specific class and for method in the class, if such is not found, out of the two I throw error page with image and title. In mistaken class name in the url I get what I expect, but if I have valid class name and not valid method name I get in different else and from there I get my desired 404 code and the title, but the image can not be displayed, because I get stuck with added /something/Assets/notfound.jpg in my request URL. Please if somebody knows a fix to help me.

My test URL:

```
http://localhost/php-mvc/users/
```

What I get in requestURL:

[image]

Here is my code in the dispetcher(index.php):

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register();

use \Controllers\ErrorController;

echo "<pre>";

$filePart = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$urlPart = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$cuttingPart = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), '', $filePart);

$realPart = str_replace($cuttingPart, '', $urlPart );



$urlArray = explode('/', $realPart);

$urlClass =  'Controllers\\'.ucfirst(array_shift($urlArray)).'Controller';

$urlMethod = array_shift($urlArray);

if(class_exists($urlClass)){
    if(is_callable(array($urlClass, $urlMethod))){
        call_user_func_array([$urlClass, $urlMethod], $urlArray);
    }
    else{
        $error = new ErrorController();
        $error->throwError();
    }
}
else{
    $error = new ErrorController();
    $error->throwError();
}
```

My ErrorController():

```
<?php


namespace Controllers;


class ErrorController{

    public function throwError(){
        require "Views/ErrorView.php";
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Oops, not found');
    }

}
```

My ErrorView.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Assets/notfound.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

and my directory:

[image]

Comment: Add a slash? `<img src="/Assets/notfound.jpg">` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<img src="../Assets/notfound.jpg">
```